# DOM is not being re-rendered after updating based on touch events (android, phone gap)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am noticing an issue with Android's webview. I'm running Android 4.0.4 on an xperia nxt. I'm not sure if the issue crosses over with other Android devices.

The issue is, I am using iScroll4, and when the scroll ends, I update the DOM. The problem is, the Android Device does not redraw the view. If I tap on the screen (no tap up is required) the view updates with my changes. At first I thought iScroll4 wasn't registering my touchend event, so I console.log upon scrollend. Sure enough, iScroll was calling my function with no issues. I don't really know what could cause this. It appears to happen when the device starts to lagg a little (maybe it's doing some process in the background?)

What's even weirder is, if I setTimeout my function for 400ms (anything lower sometimes bugs out), the view updates with no problems.

Either way, any help would be super appreciated.

Thanks,

Kyle

- edit -

Solution here: [Android WebView renders blank/white, view doesn't update on css changes or HTML changes, animations are choppy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500452/android-webview-renders-blank-white-view-doesnt-update-on-css-changes-or-html)