# Blank screen on Android 5

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, angular-touch

While developing an app wich uses phonegap, angular touch and jquery we stumble in this bug on some android devices.

When touch and move over an non scrollable object the screen goes blank.
When scrooling the body the screen comes back to life.
All the elements stays in dom and still firing events and so.
When using developer tools we still can see the elements.

http://youtu.be/NdTerKi08WE

Has any one saw this bug before?

EDIT

Im using phongegap build so i dont have access to java files.
This problem is only on Android 5 phones.

EDIT 2

Same problem on device chrome browser so its probably not an phone gap problem.

Comment: Posting a link on a video is not the correct way to do. You need to describe the problem, and use the video as a potential help on details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android WebView renders blank/white, view doesn't update on css changes or HTML changes, animations are choppy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500452/android-webview-renders-blank-white-view-doesnt-update-on-css-changes-or-html)

Comment: Im using phone gap build so i dont have acsss to the java files. any way the css hacks didn't help me.
One more i have noticed that this bug only happen in android 5+

Comment: As far as phonegap knows this problems has nothing to do with i linked question. 
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/blank-screen-on-android-touch?utm_source=notification&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=new_comment&utm_content=reply_button&reply[id]=15769689#reply_15769689

Comment: When runing the app from chrome on the device there is no problam...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was an issue regard to rtl in the new chromium.

The workaround is to add the "rtl" to css on document ready.

Comment: Instead of putting it in the <html> tag